# Http get and post request throgh proxy in python

Tags: python, post, proxy

```
import requests

proxies = {'http': '203.92.33.87:80'}

# Creating the session and setting up the proxies.
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies = proxies

# Making the HTTP request through the created session.
r = s.get('https://www.trackip.net/ip')

# Check if the proxy was indeed used (the text should contain the proxy IP).
print(r.text)
```

In above code I am expecting that print will print 203.92.33.87. 
But it is printing my real public IP.

Answer (score 2):

In your `proxies` dictionary, you only specify a proxy for protocol `http`. But in your `s.get()`, you specificy protocol `https`. Since there is no `https` key in your dictionary, no proxy is used.

If `203.92.33.87:80` is, in fact, an https proxy, then change the `proxies` dictionary to reflect that. On the other hand, if it is an http proxy, then change `s.get()` to `s.get('http://...')`.

Also, I believe you've incorrectly specified the proxy URL. According to [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies):

> Note that proxy URLs must include the scheme